# Doctrine2 Symfony2 how to ignore NULL in query builder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a route with may or may not contain values, and wish to query Doctrine based on that,

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{productType}/{region}/{town}/{road}", name="product_type" , defaults={"productType" = null , "region" = null , "town" = null , "road" = null  })
 * @Template()
 */
public function productTypeAction($productType, $region , $town , $road)
{       
    $properties = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')
    ->findBy(
    array('productType' => $productType,
          'region' => $region,
          'town' => $town,            
          'road' => $road               
    ),
    array('id' => 'ASC'));    



    return 'mytwig';
}
```

So for instance:

```
http://localhost/book/england/london/streetroad
```

Would query for Books with a region of England , a town of London and a road of Streetroad.

A route of:

```
http://localhost/book
```

Should query for Books, and return all books.

Instead, its currently just querinyg :

```
t0.productid = ? 
  AND t0.region IS NULL 
  AND t0.town IS NULL      
  AND t0.road IS NULL
```

Which makes sense, but what is the best way of getting the results I require? Or do I need to revert DQL?

Comment: It's better to use DQL

Comment: please review my answer and accept if it is what you've been looking for otherwise please add a comment what is missing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to remove NULL values from your array:

```
->findBy(array_filter(array(
      'productType' => $productType,
      'region' => $region,
      'town' => $town,            
      'road' => $road               
), 'is_null'),
```

Comment: jeah this is the short way - better solution but same concept :)

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear, but this was the reverse of my expected results. Simply removing the 'is_null' gives me the correct results, as the null are filtered out, rather than only null being invluded.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// ...

$filters =  array(
      'productType' => $productType,
      'region'      => $region,
      'town'        => $town,            
      'road'        => $road               
);
foreach ( $filters as $key => $value) {
    if ($filters[$key] === null) { 
        unset($filters[$key]); 
    }
}

// ...

    ->findBy($filters),

// ...
```

or in short form with array filter:

```
->findBy(
      array_filter(
          array(
              'productType' => $productType,
              'region' => $region,
              'town' => $town,            
              'road' => $road               
           ),
           'is_null'
      )
  )
```